# how DNS providers cooperate?

Tags: dns, cloudflare

How do all DNS providers like Google, Cloudflare and etc. agree on where an address should point to?
Why won't one company try to sell a domain, already sold to a customer by another company?

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming but here are the two subjects you need to investigate (Wikipedia has good pages on both): on the DNS (resolution) side, do learn about delegations and the difference between authoritative and recursive nameservers; on the registration path, do learn about the split between a domain name registry and a domain name registrar.

Comment: Where should I move it? @PatrickMevzek